# Test exception block with .json()

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have the following function which handles get requests in my application. How can I write a test or what `rawResponse` can potentially be mocked to for the catch block to be ever reached? Is there a way to force `.json()` to throw an exception?

```
export async function get(url) {
  let response;
  let rawResponse = {};

  try {
    rawResponse = await fetch(url);
    response = await rawResponse.json();
  } catch (err) {
    return err.toString();   // TEST THIS LINE
  }

  return response;
}
```

I have used Jest's mockResponse to mock the response to be a string, array etc. to make it go into catch block.

Comment: Use the following invalid JSON string `'<'`

Answer (score 0):

Just throw an error after the fetch or response:

```
throw new Error('Message error');
```

Comment: I don't want to throw an error every time. I wanted to reproduce and test a potential exception.